$f(s) = e^{2\pi i s}$ is not nullhomotopic relative to $ \{0,1\}$
In the following exercise
(1) Consider $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, Let  $f(s) = e^{2\pi i s}$. Show that $f$ is nullhomotopic.
(2) Let $g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ with  $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$. Show that $g$ is homotopic relative to the subset $\{0,1\}$ to the identity map.
(3)Show that $f$ from part (1) is not nullhomotopic rel $\{0,1\}$. Hint: express $f$ as a composition of a quotient map and a homeomorphism. If $f$ is nullhomotopic rel $\{0,1\}$, use this nullhomotopy and the homeomorphism to show that the identity map of $S^1$ is nullhomotopic
I am having trouble with part 3, this is what I have:
We express $f$ as a composition of two maps:

The quotient map $q : [0,1] \to S^1$, defined by
$$ q(s) = e^{2 \pi i s}, $$
which identifies the endpoints of the interval $[0,1]$ and maps it to $S^1$.
A homeomorphism $h : S^1 \to S^1$, which in this case is the identity map, i.e.,
$$ h(z) = z, $$
for all $z \in S^1$.

Thus, $f(s)$ can be written as:
$$ f(s) = h(q(s)). $$
Assume that $f$ is nullhomotopic relative to $\{0,1\}$. This means there exists a homotopy $H : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to S^1$ such that:

$H(s, 0) = f(s) = e^{2 \pi i s}$,
$H(s, 1) = c$, where $c \in S^1$ is a constant map,
$H(0, t) = H(1, t) = 1$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ (since the homotopy is relative to $\{0,1\}$).

What should I do next? I should deduce from this that the identity is nullhomotopic, but I don't see how,  I think q is also nullhomotopic to {0,1} but don't know if I can set $H(s, 0) = f(s) = e^{2 \pi i s}=q(s)$ in condition 1 above. Perhaps my choice of q and h was wrong but I don't see other option

Hint: Use the universal property of quotients to show that $f$ gives rise to a map $\tilde{f}\colon S^1 \to S^1$. What map is this? What happens if you apply the same procedure to a homotopy rel ${0, 1}$?

@BenSteffan is the choice of q and h OK?

Yes, that seems alright.

@BenSteffan I get that $\tilde f =h$, but why is that useful? I had already defined $f=h\circ q$ without having to do that. I am also lost trying to apply the universal property to the homotopy H rel {0,1}. Also I don't see the point on defining h to begin with, since it is the identity, it looks like f is already a quotient map

What I think was intended was to consider $q$ as a map $[0, 1] \to [0, 1] / {0, 1}$ and then $h$ as a homeomorphism $[0, 1] / {0, 1} \to S^1$, but the way you wrote it also works. As for the homotopy, you might want to remind yourself what being "rel ${0, 1}$" means, and how this implies that it gives you a homotopy $S^1 \times [0, 1] \to S^1$.

@BenSteffan I'll take like that since it makes more sense. relative means H(0,t)=f(0)=1 H(1,t)=f(1)=1, so the points 0 and 1 are fixed during the homotopy, But it tells me nothing regarding that other homotopy

I don't think there's anything else I could give as a hint short of giving away the solution. I can do that, of course, and write an answer if you'd prefer.

@BenSteffan  Yes please, I have been hours on this already.

As discussed in the comments, everything you've written up to this point is correct.
To finish, note that $H$ factors over $S^1 \times [0, 1]$ to give a homotopy $\tilde{H}\colon S^1 \times [0, 1] \to S^1$ since $H(0, t) = H(1, t)$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$ (the quotient map we're factoring over is $q \times \mathrm{id}_{[0, 1]}\colon [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to S^1 \times [0, 1]$). By definition, $\tilde{H}(s, 0) = h(s) = \mathrm{id}_{S^1}(s) = s$ and $\tilde{H}(s, 1) = 1$, so $\tilde{H}$ is a nullhomotopy of $\mathrm{id}_{S^1}$ of which you presumably know none exist (which follows e.g. from the fact that $\pi_1 S^1$ is non-trivial). This is a contradiction, so we conclude that no such $H$ can exist in the first place.

Can $\tilde H$ be written in terms of $H$?, to see directly why $\tilde H(s,0)=h(s) $ and $\tilde H(s,1)=1 $ ? You say by definition, but i think I should verify this properties and then say , ah it is a homotopy

@some_math_guy To the same extent that $h$ can be written in terms of $f$: If we write $h_t(s) = H(s, t)$ and similar $\tilde{h}_t(s) = \tilde{H}(s, t)$, then you have $h_t = \tilde{h}_t \circ q$ for all $t$, in analogy to $f = h \circ q$. To put it more directly, $\tilde{H}(s, t) = H(s', t)$, where $s' \in [0, 1]$ is any point such that $q(s') = s$ (this is how factoring over a quotient works in general).

I am considering $h(s):[0,1]/{0,1}→S^1$ and $q:[0,1]\mapsto [0,1]/\sim$ as you described in your third comment above, but then using the $q\times id_{[0,1]}$ to lift $H to \tilde H$ yields $\tilde H(s,0)=H(s,0)=f(s)=e^{2\pi i s}$ instead of $id_{[0,1]}$, how do I fix that?

@some_math_guy I think you've confused yourself. First off all, $h_0 = \tilde{H}({{-}}, 0)$ will never be $\mathrm{id}_{[0, 1]}$, that simply doesn't make sense since both domain an codomain are $S^1$. You know that $h_0 = f$, and that $h_0 = \tilde{h}0 \circ q$, and that $f = h \circ q = \mathrm{id}{S^1} \circ q$. Put these together to obtain that $\tilde{h}0 = h = \mathrm{id}{S^1}$.
